# Pandas.read_csv() ParserError

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to read csv file in Python using Pandas.read_csv() method. I am confused about one thing. When first line of data in csv file is longer than headers line, no error is raised. However when the second line is longer, ParserError occured. Could you tell me why it happens?

My code:

```
import pandas


a = pandas.read_csv('file.csv')
print(a)
```

Csv file with first line longer and output:

```
a,b,c
4,6,4,5
1,2,3

   a  b    c
4  6  4  5.0
1  2  3  NaN
```

Csv with second line longer and output:

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,6,4,5

Exception has occurred: ParserError
Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 3, saw 4
  File "C:\Users\user\TRAINING\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    a = pandas.read_csv('file.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [IO tools docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html)

> **index_col: int, str, sequence of int / str, or False, optional, default
> None**
>
> Column(s) to use as the row labels of the DataFrame, either given as string name or column index. If a sequence of int / str is given, a
> MultiIndex is used.
>
> **Note**: index_col=False can be used to force pandas to not use the first column as the index, e.g. when you have a malformed file with
> delimiters at the end of each line.
>
> The default value of None instructs pandas to guess. If the number of fields in the column header row is equal to the number of fields in
> the body of the data file, then a default index is used. If it is
> larger, then the first columns are used as index so that the remaining
> number of fields in the body are equal to the number of fields in the
> header.
>
> The first row after the header is used to determine the number of columns, which will go into the index. If the subsequent rows contain
> less columns than the first row, they are filled with NaN.
>
> This can be avoided through usecols. This ensures that the columns are taken as is and the trailing data are ignored.